# Rewriting a dll file when using MEF and WCF

Tags: wcf, dll, assemblies, mef, overwrite

On my current project, I'm sending dll files to clients using a WCF service.
The dll files contain UserControls which the clients use to visualize data.
However, sometimes new UserControls are introduced by the service, without the clients knowing about this. When this happend, I send the new dll file to the clients so they have the latest version of the UserControls.

However, when I want to write this new dll file on the clients HD (using a FileStream), I get an exception saying that the file is used by another process (of course, the clients always have an assembly version of the UserControls on their HD, so this has to be overwriten).

Is there any way to overwrite this file without getting an error? I'm using MEF to read the assembly files in the client project. To send the assembly file to the clients, I just send the filename as a string and the file's content in a byte array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is usually done with [Shadow Copying](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404279.aspx), but I can't find anything definitive as to whether it works with MEF.

If its acceptable for your new control to be loaded on closing and re-opening the application, then you can copy all your plugins prior to composing with MEF.

Here is a [blog post](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2008/10/05/reading-mef-code.aspx) with somebody essentially trying MEF + Shodow Copy, and a particularly relevant comment.

> The fundamental problem here is that
>   .NET doesn't support dynamic assembly
>   unloading. You could reload the
>   assembly, but you would never be able
>   to recover the memory used by the old
>   one

Comment: Thank you! When a new control is introduced, I will send a restart command to the clients. When the client is started, I will overwrite the assembly BEFORE the controls are loaded with MEF. This should work.